# Routing an internet connection to 2 VLANs using an EdgeCore ECS2100 Series

Tags: networking, router, routing, switch, vlan

The L3 Switch in question is an EdgeCore ECS2100 series.

Basically I would like to have 2 VLANs/network segments/broadcast domains/whatever you want to call it, and share an internet connection with both VLANs.

- VLAN 1 talks to VLAN 2 across my layer 3 switch (which it can currently).
- VLAN 2 can also talk to VLAN 1 across the layer 3 switch.

Both VLANs should then have a route to the internet (`0.0.0.0/0` static route) which happens to be on a third network segment.

[image: VLANs]

- VLAN 1: `172.17.0.0/20`, L3 switch port `172.17.0.254`
- VLAN 2: `172.16.0.0/20`, L3 switch port `172.16.0.254`
- VLAN 3: `172.18.0.0/20`, L3 switch port `172.18.0.254`. This segment also has my internet connection on the gateway 172.18.0.1`.

[image: Routing Interfaces]

[image: Routing Table]

The problem is VLAN 1 or VLAN 2 can't talk to the internet, however anything on `172.18.0.0/20` can (even when I point the default gateway to `172.18.0.254`, so the switch is smart enough to route traffic to `172.18.0.1`, the "next hop").

So routing within the switch/between subnets within the switch works fine, it just refuses to route anything NOT on VLAN 3 to my internet connection on `172.18.0.1.`

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to be sure, _is_ L3 routing enabled on the switch at all? Although the switch will have IP interfaces and a routing table for itself (i.e. management), that doesn't necessarily mean it'll forward packets; sometimes you have to explicitly enable L3 routing. Do you have access to the gateway at 172.18.0.1, and can you verify that the gateway isn't _receiving_ any packets from the other subnets?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the suggestion. I think in these routers the "Enable Routing" is implicit. Although you can enable/disable L3 functions on a per-VLAN basis. See my answer below - the problem was the return routing from the upstream router. I guess the reason I've never run into this problem before is because for other situations that are more "normal", a NAT translation would preclude the necessity for a return route?

Comment: I wouldn't say more "normal" (NAT despite its popularity is still an add-on hack – it's not the "normal" way routing is done, *especially* not inside a network), but yes, masquerading or SNAT would usually make things appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working thanks to a couple of suggestions on another forum

The attached screenshot is from the upstream router that I talked my way into (by asking the provider nicely), and all that was needed was a couple of routes from the upstream router's "LAN" interface to my other two VLANed subnets.

Upstream router's Static Routes back to my subnets:
[image: Static routes]

(If the image is 404'd, the routes I added were:

```
172.17.0.0/20 -> 172.18.0.254
172.16.0.0/20 -> 172.18.0.254
```

Easy!